# Assign new row to DataSource column of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I create ComboBox dinamically depending of Data received from dataSource. So I have code like this:

```
 private static ComboBox DoCreateComboBox(DataTable empList, int yPoint, int xComboPoint, DataRow task)

        {

        var currentEmpGuid = task["EmpGuid"];
        var recalculatedEmpGuid = "";
        if (currentEmpGuid.Equals(Guid.Empty))
        {
            recalculatedEmpGuid = "Unassigned";
        }
        else
        {
            recalculatedEmpGuid = currentEmpGuid.ToString();
        }

            //Creating ComboBox
            return new ComboBox()
        {
            DisplayMember = "Name",
            ValueMember = "EmpGuid",
            BindingContext = new BindingContext(),
            DataSource = empList,
            SelectedValue = recalculatedEmpGuid,
            DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
            Location = new Point(xComboPoint, yPoint),
            Tag = task
        };
```

As you can see, I have recalculatedValue depending of `Guid` Received. I want to know how can I add Unassigned value to my `empList` in order to use as `SelectedValue` Property on `Combobox`.

To be more simple I just need to add new Row with value "Unassigned" to `task["EmpGuid"]` column
 How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Just add or insert the row into the empList DataTable.

Comment: That's my question. How can I achieve that? @LarsTech

Comment: `DataRow dr = empList.NewRow();`  Set your column data.  Then add it to the table: `empList.Rows.Add(dr);` or `empList.Rows.Insert(dr, 0);`